# AWS RDS cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an alarm for "FreeStorageSpace" metric and units it takes is Bytes. What, however, I am trying to do is create an alarm using percentages (send an alarm is FreeStorageSpace < 10%) and not hardcode values. How can I create a CFT for that and reuse it for instances having different storage values.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please `Accept` and `Upvote` my answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `%` value while creating the `FreeStorageSpace` alarm in `CloudWatch`. Also, the alarms in AWS are on per instance basis. You can not create a generic alarm for multiple instances. Hence, you may use numeric value for defining the alarm.

Comment: Moinuddin, appreciate the reply.I have 2 issues here:

1) I am trying to create a CloudFormation template which can deployed and redeployed for several instances (which is possible as I am already doing it using DBInstanceIdentifier property of CW alarms).
2) The piece of information I missed is that I am creating alarms for RDS and not EC2 (FWIW).

Let me know if that helps to adjust your answer.

Thanks